# How to add border to a button in python for Tkinter?

Tags: python, button, tkinter

```
b1 = Button(tk, text=" ", font=("Consolas 30 bold"), height = 1, width = 4,bg = "white", command=lambda:checker(b1))
```

What piece of code to I add to this to add a border to the button, as in making it thicker?

Comment: please consider researching a bit more prior to posting a question.

Comment: In regards to glls's comment above: SO is useful as a resource for people to find answers to questions, even years later (I just found it because I had PRECISELY the same use case and question). With your statement you have not provided anything useful towards Rory Daulton, as well as other people who may come here to try to find answers. Please refrain from telling other people what to do in this regard. Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

as per http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/button.htm:

```
borderwidth= variable
```

> The width of the button border. The default is platform specific, but
>   is usually 1 or 2 pixels. (borderWidth/BorderWidth)

not to be confused with:

```
highlightthickness= variable
```

> The width of the highlight border. The default is system specific
>   (usually one or two pixels). (highlightThickness/HighlightThickness)

Comment: `highlightthickness` is not the same as a border, it's more like a ring around the button. A border is controlled with `borderwidth` and `relief`.